# ranges v3 any_view & constant

Tags: c++, visual-c++, range-v3

The following trivial code is failing:

```
#include <vector>
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> const v{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    ranges::any_view<int, ranges::category::bidirectional |
                              ranges::category::sized> const a{v};
    ranges::begin(a);
}
```

but if remove the constant here:

```
 a { v };
```

everything is OK. Is it a bug? Or do I not understand the semantics of `any_view`.

UPD: This is MSVC 16.9.0 Preview 1.0 compiler.

Answer (score 1):

`ranges::begin(a)` invokes

```
template<typename R>
ranges::_begin_::fn::operator ()(R && r)
```

that expects modifiable or r-value parameter `r`.

`a` declared as `const a{v}` would call `ranges::_begin_::fn::operator ()<const ranges::any_view<...>>(const ranges::any_view<...> && r)` that is not possible since it would bind r-value `a` to l-value parameter.

Comment: I guess && is universal reference, not rvalue reference here. But I'm more interested why the following code is working     auto const b = v | ranges::views::transform([](auto i){ return i + 1; });
    ranges::begin(b); with constant and w/o it. It looks like inconsistence.

Comment: Right, the universal reverence can be deduced to both generic reference or r-value reference. If the overload `ranges::_begin_::fn::operator ()(const R & r)` would exist, it would cause an ambiguity while deducing template parameters between `const R & r` and `const R && r` for `const a`.